# How to Open a Transparent SherlockActivity with ActionBar over a SherlockActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, transparent, actionbarsherlock

I want to open a transparent SherlockActivity with Actionbar over a SherlockActivity. Please check the attached screenshot.

How can I achieve this kind of layout with ActionBarSherlock?

[image: layout]

Bigger image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-YGQsgT4dyHU/UCp0ohkAHyI/AAAAAAAAB-M/4DDmBML8m5M/s1600/fancy_screenshot_2.png

Comment: Any comments about this issue?